# Generate md5 hash of JSON and compare in Python and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, hash, md5

I have a use case where i have to generate `md5` hash of a `JSON` object and compare the hashes in the server and the browser.

The browser client generates hash and then asks the server for the hash of the same resource[ which happens to be a JSON object], and compares both the hashes to decide what to do next.

For server i am using `Python` and browser client is in `Javascript`.

For me the hashes generated in both cases do not match. Here's my code:

**Python**:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import json

>>> a = {"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}
>>> a = json.dumps(a, sort_keys = True).encode("utf-8")
>>> hashlib.md5(a).hexdigest()
>>> 12db79ee4a76db2f4fc48624140adc7e
```

**JS**:
I am using [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) for hashing in browser

```
> var hash = require("md5")
> var data = {"candidate":5, "data":1}
> data = JSON.stringify(data)
> md5(data)
> 92e99f0a99ad2a3b5e02f717a2fb83c2
```

What is it that i am doing wrong?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/emn178/js-md5) library gives the correct hash (Python's)

Comment: Note however that converting JS to string is not the best approach: white spaces, formatting, even the order of 2 keys could be different yet semantically the docs are the same. I have not found a lib for python yet but for javascript there is https://github.com/fraunhoferfokus/JSum. For Python, https://github.com/schollii/sandals/blob/master/json_sem_hash.py.

Comment: `md5` is not secure. Better to use something modern like `sha384` or `sha256`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're assuming that both languages generate JSON that looks identical.

```
>>> json.dumps({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}, sort_keys=True)
'{"candidate": 5, "data": 1}'

js> JSON.stringify({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1})
"{\"candidate\":5,\"data\":1}"
```

Fortunately, they can.

```
>>> a = json.dumps({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
'{\n  "candidate": 5,\n  "data": 1\n}'

js> var a = JSON.stringify({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}, null, 2)
"{\n  \"candidate\": 5,\n  \"data\": 1\n}"
```

And now the hashes would be same as well.

Python:

```
>>> hashlib.md5(a.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
>>> d77982d217ec5a9bcbad5be9bee93027
```

JS:

```
>>> md5(a)
>>> d77982d217ec5a9bcbad5be9bee93027
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to hash from my JS REPL.

Comment: I believe this answer is invalid, because in the Python snipet ordering is being enforced, while in the JavaScript version it is arbitrary, in fact, it's not guaranteed to follow any specific ordering by the docs:


_Note: Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification._


The same example with the following would fail:
```{"data" : 5, "candidate": 1}```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that **`json.dumps`** applies some minor pretty-printing by default but **`JSON.stringify`** does not, that's why hashes are not the same.

  Python:

```py
 >>> import json
 >>> json.dumps({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1})
     '{"candidate": 5, "data": 1}'
```

Javacript:

```
 > JSON.stringify({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1})
   '{"candidate":5,"data":1}'
```

But with some modification, we can generate the same hash. There are two ways for it:-

1. Modifying `javascript JSON string` to make it equivalent to a `python JSON string`.

    Python:

   ```py
   >>> import json,hashlib
   >>> a = json.dumps({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}, sort_keys=True)
   >>> hashlib.md5(a.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
       '12db79ee4a76db2f4fc48624140adc7e'
   ```

   Javacript:

   ```
   > const Crypto = require("crypto-js")
     undefined
   > const a = JSON.stringify({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}).replaceAll(":", ": ").replaceAll(",", ", ")
     undefined
   > Crypto.MD5(a).toString(Crypto.enc.Hex)
     '12db79ee4a76db2f4fc48624140adc7e'
   ```
2. Modifying `python JSON string` to make it equivalent to a `javascript JSON string`.

    Python:

   ```py
   >>> import json,hashlib
   >>> a = json.dumps({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1}, separators=(',', ':'))
   >>> hashlib.md5(a.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
       '92e99f0a99ad2a3b5e02f717a2fb83c2'
   ```

   Javacript:

   ```
   > const Crypto = require("crypto-js")
     undefined
   > const a = JSON.stringify({"candidate" : 5, "data": 1})
     undefined
   > Crypto.MD5(a).toString(Crypto.enc.Hex)
     '92e99f0a99ad2a3b5e02f717a2fb83c2'
   ```

   > Note:- To run javascript code, crypto-js npm pkg should be installed as same location where you started the node shell.

Comment: Super helpful for me, the crux of my issue was the `separators` option.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I created this python module [merkle-json](https://pypi.org/project/merkle-json) which can generate a unique hash no matter the order of the list or the key inside a dict or json object.
It offers also some flexible and additional configurations where you can ignore keys, or null values based on your needs, check the docs for more.

use it like this:

```py
from merkle_json import MerkleJson

mj = MerkleJson()

obj = {
    'keyC': [3,4],
    'keyA': 2,
    'keyB': 4,
    'keyD': 1,
}
mjHash = mj.hash(obj)
print(mjHash) # '7001bd2b415e6a624a23d7bc7c249b21'
```